# Embedded MongoDB with Spring not working

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux

I am trying to create a Spring application with WebFlux and an embedded MongoDB. However, even if my tests runs perfectly, I can't start my application because it seems that embedded mongodb has not started.

The exception that I get is the following:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

2018-03-25 17:47:15.372  INFO 14188 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$2.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$2.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:145) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:327) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:343) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
 Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.lorescianatico</groupId>
<artifactId>driftcoin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>driftcoin</name>
<description>Driftcoin project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

My application properties is just a blank file. My repository class is the following:

```
package com.lorescianatico.driftcoin.repository;

import com.lorescianatico.driftcoin.model.BlockChain;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;

public interface BlockChainRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<BlockChain, String> {
}
```

As you can see, I am using reactive repository for mongodb. I already tried to activate via annotations reactive repositories but it didn't change the exception. Am I missing something, like a configuration or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you see in your error, your MongoDB server is not up, your application is trying to connect to MongoDB but mongo is down, can you check that

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I checked lots of examples of Spring application with an embedded MongoDB. It seems that the embedded MongoDB server does not start, and I can't find any configurations to make it start.

Comment: can you provide your MongoDB properties, there is no embedded mongo in spring boot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your embedded mongodb is set to be used when you are testing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove the test scope from there so you can use it at runtime:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well... in fact you are right. A colleague solved the issue and I didn't notice the change. Thank you!

Comment: @gumoi in which file is this? I do not see it

Comment: @likejudo, which build tool do you use? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: XML syntax is proper from maven. A runtime scope solve issue when running the app and tests: <scope>runtime</scope>

Answer (score 6):

have you added these mongo properties in your application.properites

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=app1
```

[spring boot mongo example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-mongodb-example/)

this link would be helpful to solve your problem

Comment: Already tried... It seems that Spring search for a MongoDB located at localhost at that port, but the embedded mongodb does not start.

Comment: Ok, this is really strange, but after a couple of tentatives it worked. I can't get why it did not work at the first try.

Comment: This is happening to me too. Any idea what caused the change? @Lorelorelore

Comment: @Avner Levy Are you using the embedded mongo for test purpose or for runtime purpose?

Comment: @Lorelorelore I tried to use it for runtime purpuse. It starts in the generated test but not in app runtime. Thanks

Comment: Check your pom.xml. Maybe you have the test scope, while you need a runtime scope.

Comment: @raval tailor where is application.properties? I am using gradle and intellij community edition

Answer (score 1):

When using grade I got the same problem and the issue was with my build.gradle solved it by changing this line:

testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')

to

compile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')

So issue has to be in your pom the embedded mongodb is not being setup.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing mongo on the VM and then running the Spring boot instance.

For me the embedded mongo driver (de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) was not working, so I removed the dependancy.

1. Install Mongo & run it

   - sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
   - echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
   - sudo service mongod restart
2. Run Spring Boot Application

Answer (score -3):

Posting my solution, as it may help someone - I've added version to`de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` dependency and it did a trick:

Use this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

instead of this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Maven repository link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.flapdoodle.embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo